# Django DeleteView Not Saving Changes

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm using django DeleteView to delete user account. when i set the user's is_active property to False, it doesn't get saved in the database. it's still set to True

here's my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class DeleteAccount(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    """
    DeleteAccount: view to delete user account
    """

    model = User
    template_name = 'registration/delete_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:index')
    success_message = 'Account Successfully Deleted!'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Delete account and logout current user
        """

        account = self.get_object()

        # verify if user is the rightful owner of this account
        if not account.id == self.request.user.id:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('accounts:index'))

        account.is_active = False # DOESN'T GET SAVED
        account.save() # EVEN AFTER CALLING MODEL.SAVE() METHOD

        logout(self.request)

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk = self.request.user.id)
```

Comment: A `DeleteView` has no `form_valid` (and hence does not call it either). It just deletes the item.

Comment: it does, according to this url: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/

Comment: ah yes, that was introduced in Django-4.0. In Django-3.0 it was a simple delete of the object https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/

Comment: Do you use a custom user model?

Comment: yes, i', using a custom user model